# How to localize for Windows Phone based on OS version

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, localization, globalization

I'm building a Windows Phone application and my client has given me a list of languages that he would like the App to be localized for.

The problem is that some of those languages are not supported by Windows Phone and I then decided to check out the list of supported langauges which is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202918%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). I noticed that there are two OS option for Windows Phone, i.e. 7.0 and 7.1 but during development I am not sure of how to check for which OS the phone is running so that I know which list of languages to supply to the user.

I'd like to know how to check if the Windows Phone OS is 7.0 or 7.1 (I'm assuming that his caters for later OS versions that might have come after the list was created)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [Windows Phone Team Blog post](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2012/05/22/starting-today-you-need-windows-phone-7-5-to-use-marketplace.aspx).

Microsoft already stopped the support for OS 7.0, so you don't need to worry about 7.0. GO ahead with 7.1

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is closing it's marketplace for devices running Windows Phone 7.0. So you shouldn't need to check if it's a 7.0 device, since your app probably won't be installed on one of those.

Here is an article describing this.
http://www.mofonu.com/2012/04/26/windows-phone-marketplace-closing-its-doors-to-devices-not-running-mango/